# Odoo: Override state in purchase order

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I've overridden state field in purchase order module and add compute function to that field but I got stuck with loading screen. [The screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztw5m.png)

Here is my sample code:

```
_inherit = "purchase.order"

@api.depends('my_field')
def _my_compute_field(self):
    for order in self:
        if not order.my_field:
            order.state = 'draft'

state = fields.Selection([
    ('draft', 'RFQ'),
    ('sent', 'RFQ Sent'),
    ('to approve', 'To Approve'),
    ('purchase', 'Purchase Order'),
    ('done', 'Locked'),
    ('fully', 'PO Closed - Fully Received'),
    ('partial', 'PO Closed - Partial Received'),
    ('cancel', 'Cancelled')        
    ], string='Status', readonly=True, index=True, copy=False, default='draft', store=True, compute='_my_compute_field', track_visibility='onchange')
```

I got the cause of this issue It was my depend field which is compute field and set store=True.

After I tried to set the field to store=False the loading screen is gone but I cannot get value from the field in my compute function because it's not saved into db.

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: If you set computed field to `store=True` it will need to compute the value beforehand and store it in the database. This could be a reason why you see a loading screen. It will take time if you have a lot of `purchase.order` to process first. But the problem I see with your code is that the only state possible for your `purchase.order` will be draft.

Comment: Even if it was with `store=True` or `store=False` the value of the state can only be set in the compute method. You can't get it from there.

Comment: Sorry @LoïcFaure-Lacroix, I missed my point, So my point was I tried to use compute method with the state field (store=True) and I set @api.depends('order_line.product_qty', 'order_line.qty_received') I want it triggers when those fields have been changed and then update the state field. But before that I have a wizard form to generate purchase.order.line in my active purchase.order then after I clicked generate button on the wizard form to execute function the infinite loading screen happen.

PS. The button works well before I created the compute method and add it into the state field.

Comment: better post the actual code then.